# Imagem em e-mail HTML no PHPMailer

Tags: html, phpmailer

Estou fazendo um template para envio de e-mail marketing, que contém uma imagem:

```
<tr>
   <td style="padding: 10px 0 10px 0;" align="center" bgcolor="#1ac6ff">
      <img src="templates/email/logo.png" alt="Ticket" style="display: inline; padding: 0 20px 0 20px;" height="auto" width="auto" />
   </td>
</tr>
```

Mas a imagem não vai para o e-mail (claro, está com endereço local).

Pelo `PHPMailer`, existe uma forma de "anexar" a imagem junto para usá-la ou terei que fazer o upload em um serviço de imagens ?

O problema no caso de servidor de imagens, seria esse link sair fora do ar um dia, e assim perder todos os e-mails anteriores, correto !?

Comment: Eu ia te sugerir um Base64, mas parece que o Gmail não aceita. Se te interessar da uma olhada aqui https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16242489/send-a-base64-image-in-html-email

Comment: Achei isso: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3708153/send-email-with-phpmailer-embed-image-in-body, mas não está funcionando... estou conferindo ! rs Obrigado

Comment: Mas em vista é esse `$mail->AddEmbeddedImage`

Comment: Parasse que esse é o caminho!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilizando o método `$mail->AddEmbeddedImage`:

`$mail->AddEmbeddedImage('img/logo.jpg', 'logo_ref');`

Na tag `<img>` insere: `src='cid:logo_ref'`.

Dessa forma, a imagem ficará embutida no e-mail.